# Debian fails to prompt for encrypted disk password on boot

Tags: debian, boot, dm-crypt, disk-encryption

I am using Debian Scratch with encrypted root partition. The last kernel version where it worked was 4.6.0. For kernels 4.7.0 and 4.8.0 it prints on the boot repeatedly and forever following messages:

```
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  Volume group "martin-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group martin-vg
```

In 4.6.0 these messages are shown too, but only twice and then it prompts for a password:

```
Please unlock disk sda5_crypt:
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Don't fix it, just fill a bugreport. Debian Stretch is an unstable/testing distribution, not recommended for reallife usage.

Comment: @IporSircer done.

Comment: @MartinŽdila Can you, please, give us the link to your bug report?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni it is Bug#844487 (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.kernel/iue2f-9938g)

Comment: @MartinŽdila Thanks. Personally I prefer accessing debian bugs via https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844487